# Read viminfo when argc() > 0

Tags: buffers, sessions, viminfo

Does Vim read the `viminfo` when called with a file argument?

How can I force Vim to restore the buffer list in that case?

**Use case & context**

What I want is:

- When called as `vi`: enable read/write `viminfo`.
- When called as `vi some-file`: disable write `viminfo`, read `viminfo` on demand.

I mainly interested with buffer list & marks.

Comment: I have slightly reformulate your question based on what I understood. Feel free to revert my changes if I corrupt it ;-)

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem? Could you share it with us?

Comment: Not working on it now. If later working on it, will come back and post my findings. Though I think parsing viminfo file might be the only viable choice as of today.

Answer (score 0):

## Buffer List

The buffer list is not saved into the .viminfo file when Vim is called with a file argument (see `:help viminfo` and look at the `%` section)

```
%       When included, save and restore the buffer list.  If Vim is
        started with a file name argument, the buffer list is not
        restored.  If Vim is started without a file name argument, the
        buffer list is restored from the viminfo file.
```

And not only the buffer list is not read at startup if Vim is started with a file name argument but a call to `:rv` will skip the buffer list section of the .viminfo file in such case.

If you want to save the list of buffer loaded the standard way is to use session.

You can restore automatically the session at startup using the following line to insert into your .vimrc:

```
autocmd GUIEnter * so ~\vimfiles\session\startup
```

To automatically make sure the startup session is updated you can use [startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) and use the following code to restore your session at start:

```
autocmd VimEnter * SLoad startup
```

Something similar could be achieve using [obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession).

Otherwise you can manage your session manually:

- You can create a session with the command: `:mksession path`
- You can read a session with the command: `:so path`

## .viminfo control

The .viminfo file contains different information about the state of Vim (you can control that using the `viminfo` option) in particular it can contains:

- The position of the marks (both local to buffers and global)
- The value of the buffers

The .viminfo file is read even if you specify the file to be open in the command line.
e.g.:

```
vim myfile
```

But uou can disable Vim to read the .viminfo at startup using the `-i None` option:

```
vim -i None
```

If you want Vim not to automatically write the .viminfo file at exit you can run the following command:

```
:set viminfo=
```

Remark: The `viminfo` variable control what will be written in the .viminfo file.

You can also:

- Force Vim to read the .viminfo using the command: `:rv`
- Force Vim to write the .viminfo using the command: `:wv`

Comment: Yes. I tried with `:rv`. But It has no effect when start with `vim some-file`. `:ls` clearly no change. Also, already `set viminfo='1024,f1,%2048,s10,<1000,h` in my vimrc.

Comment: You mentioned `:ls` what information do you expect to be read from the .viminfo? Do you expect the .viminfo file to contains the current working directory?

Comment: I understand your question better. With the `%` you can have your buffer list loaded. But the documentation says that it ignore the buffer list if a file to open is specified in the command line.

Comment: Yes, my problem is how to restore buffers save in viminfo manually when start vim with some file, aka, arg list not empty. By default viminfo is ignored as the docs says.

Comment: In my test too. If you open a Vim specifying a file in the command line not only the buffer list is not read but the call the `:rv` will skip the buffer list section. It is not the case if you don't open Vim specifying a file in the command line (the buffer list section is read by the `:rv` command)

Comment: Yes, when args non-empty, `:rv` has no effect regarding buffers. I searched `function-list` with `viminfo` but nothing. I thought if no api for this, parsing viminfo file might be the last resort.

Comment: Indeed, unless you start to use sessions and automatic session management.